# html to chm file under linux

Tags: html, linux, chm

I have html files/Directories, I want to convert them to .chm help file, under Linux using command lines at Terminal?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Free Pascal compiler, version 2.4.4 or higher has a CHM compiler for *nix called "chmcmd".  I would recommend getting it from version 2.6.0. It works on MSHelp .hhp project files.

The compiler is also available in source (styled like a classes library), so you could roll your own. It is crossplatform, but Big Endian platforms are not tested very well.

2.6.0 is from januari 1st 2012, so you might need to get it from a "bleeding edge" packages repository of your distribution.

Comment: after downloading and installing Pascal compiler on linux pc ,what i should do now ,how to use it?

Comment: As said just chmcmd <your.hpp> project file. Search on the web how to craft a hpp file, it is the same as the workshop format.

Comment: i have tried this 
chmcmd filename.hhp 
this file contains names of html files to include in chm file ,but some of them is listed in directories ,so this command give me :
Warning: File directoryName\fileName.html does not exist
for each file placed in directory even for images and css files

Comment: maybe a / vs \ problem ? Try replacing all \'s to /'s and try again

Comment: yes thnx that was the problem , but after opening the chm file and goes to contents tab and click over the headers inside directories the pages does not opened

Comment: You don't need to install the whole Free Pascal compiler. `chmcmd` utility resides in `fp-utils` package and can be installed just by `sudo apt-get install fp-utils` (at least on Ubuntu 14.04.4).

Comment: (the division into packages is something distribution specific)

Comment: if I have .html then how I can convert it to .chm

Comment: Write a HHP project for it, and compile with chmcmd or the mshelp compiler.

Comment: I have to do it on Linux Ubuntu 14.04, I need to automate this process. Is it possible?

Comment: I guess so, you could use a template .hhp and then fix the names with awk or tr or so and then compile with chmcmd

Comment: As you suggested I tried to convert .hhp to chm using chmcmd. getting below error 
An unhandled exception occurred at $0000000000405A6A :
EFCreateError : Unable to create file ""
  $0000000000405A6A
  $0000000000401083
  $00000000004005E6
### This how my .hhp file looks like                                                   
[OPTIONS]

[FILES]
/home/jenkins/Elina_Doc_Generated/Service.fidl.net.connman_Service.html

Comment: Seems your shell has no writepermissions in the curent directory

Comment: it has the write permission, and i have tried as root user. still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

`CHM` is a proprietary Microsoft format, so keep in mind most Open Source tools will likely be focused on reading and converting `chm to html` . if you want to create CHM file on Linux then you will need a `CHM compiler` that you can use with wine . details are on the following link [Compiling_CHM_help_files_in_Linux_with_HHC_and_Wine](http://www.mrpt.org/Compiling_CHM_help_files_in_Linux_with_HHC_and_Wine)

Comment: how i can use it, under linux?exe file does not open on linux

Comment: first install `wine` on linux. using `wine` you can open some supported `.exe` files on linux. provided `chm compiler` is one of them.

Comment: see if this link can help you .i have not used it but this claims to work on linux. http://linux.softpedia.com/progDownload/Rahman-CHM-Maker-Download-45103.html

Comment: how these applications would help me in creating the chm file through terminal

Comment: please go through the README.txt file of tool.

Comment: raj_gt: that tool seems to be based on older chmcmd versions. Homepage is MIA.   Ms Htmlhelp workshop via Wine is an option though

Answer (score -2):

You can do that with libchm, you find it http://www.jedrea.com/chmlib/ .

It contains extract_chmLib, which extracts html pages from the help pages to a directory.

Comment: My version of libchm says "currently does not has write support" (sic)

Comment: have you see the extract_chmLib here https://github.com/jedwing/CHMLib/blob/master/src/extract_chmLib.c ?

Comment: Yes, but extracting is reading, not writing. CHMLIB has no write support, at least not in released versions.